# How can you remove duplicate records with the deleted field value false?

Tags: mysql

The following query returns a list of email records with the number of times repeated.?

`SELECT email, COUNT(*) count FROM customers GROUP BY email HAVING count > 1 ORDER BY count DESC;`

Result

```
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| email                                | count |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| aaamedianamail@gmail.com             |     2 |
| aaaarialal@mail.ru                   |     2 |
| aaaa-aaaaosa@gmail.com               |     2 |
| aaa-t@gmail.com                      |     2 |
| aaaaa_aaa@hotmail.com                |     2 |
| aaaaamil@hotmail.com                 |     2 |
| ameaaaaanaa@hotmail.com              |     2 |
| aaaaaa@gmail.com                     |     2 |
| aqqqgmx.net                          |     2 |
```

For each pair of emails there is a record with the deleted field set to false and another set to true

```
mysql> SELECT id, name, deleted FROM customers where email = "aqqqgmx.net";
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+
| id                                   | name                       | deleted |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+
| b4afc635-145a-f735-a2d2-6421584cd55f | Ada                        |       1 |
| d4b5952b-de3e-3b3c-d0d5-641e1a83aef1 | Ada                        |       0 |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+
```

How can I delete all the records with deleted to true and that are duplicates?

Comment: If you've just introduced that `deleted` column and need to populate it first, then that's a different question. But let's just assume that you already have a `deleted` column and it's _correctly_ populated, you have other choice than deleting the row from table, simply filter them in your query like `WHERE deleted=0/1`. If you insist on deleting it anyway, then shouldn't you just do `DELETE FROM customers WHERE deleted=1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `inner join` to join the customers with the list of duplicated emails as follows :

```
delete c
from customers c
inner join (
  SELECT email
  FROM customers 
  GROUP BY email 
  HAVING count(email) > 1
) s on s.email = c.email
where c.deleted = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Fo_PzQGv)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for answering. The query removes each duplicate record, that is, it removes those whose deleted field has a value of 1 or 0. I hope it only removes those with a deleted value of 1.

Comment: I thought about moving the deleted = true condition to the having clause inside the inner join but I get `unknown column 'deleted'` in 'having clause'. I try the following:

`DELETE c FROM customers c INNER JOIN (SELECT email FROM customers GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(email) > 1 AND deleted = 1) s ON s.email = c.email;`

Comment: It remove only emails with flag deleted from duplicated only, check demo https://dbfiddle.uk/Fo_PzQGv

Comment: Thanks. My mistake dbfiddle help a lot